# Trying to understand Pytorch's implementation of LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I have a dataset containing 1000 examples where each example has **5** features (a,b,c,d,e). I want to feed **7** examples to an LSTM so it predicts the feature (a) of the 8th day.

Reading Pytorchs documentation of nn.LSTM() I came up with the following:

```
input_size = 5
hidden_size = 10
num_layers = 1
output_size = 1

lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers)
fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

out, hidden = lstm(X)  # Where X's shape is ([7,1,5])
output = fc(out[-1])

output  # output's shape is ([7,1])
```

According to the docs:

The input of the nn.LSTM is "*input of shape (**seq_len, batch, input_size***)" with "*input_size – The number of expected features in the input x*",

And the output is: "output of shape (**seq_len, batch, num_directions * hidden_size**): tensor containing the output features (h_t) from the last layer of the LSTM, for each t."

In this case, I thought `seq_len` would be the sequence of 7 examples, `batch`is 1 and `input_size` is 5. So the lstm would consume each example containing 5 features refeeding the hidden layer every iteration.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

When I extend your code to a full example -- I also added some comments to may help -- I get the following:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

input_size = 5
hidden_size = 10
num_layers = 1
output_size = 1

lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers)
fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

X = [
    [[1,2,3,4,5]],
    [[1,2,3,4,5]],
    [[1,2,3,4,5]],
    [[1,2,3,4,5]],
    [[1,2,3,4,5]],
    [[1,2,3,4,5]],
    [[1,2,3,4,5]],
]

X = torch.tensor(X, dtype=torch.float32)

print(X.shape)         # (seq_len, batch_size, input_size) = (7, 1, 5)
out, hidden = lstm(X)  # Where X's shape is ([7,1,5])
print(out.shape)       # (seq_len, batch_size, hidden_size) = (7, 1, 10)
out = out[-1]          # Get output of last step
print(out.shape)       # (batch, hidden_size) = (1, 10)
out = fc(out)          # Push through linear layer
print(out.shape)       # (batch_size, output_size) = (1, 1)
```

This makes sense to me, given your `batch_size = 1` and `output_size = 1` (I assume, you're doing regression). I don't know where your `output.shape = (7, 1)` come from.

Are you sure that your `X` has the correct dimensions? Did you create `nn.LSTM` maybe with `batch_first=True`? There are lot of little things that can sneak in.

Comment: Since `seq_len=7` each iteration of the lstm will consume a line of X containing [1,2,3,4,5], right? I'm having trouble in visualiazing what the lstm is doing each iteration.

Comment: The term "line" might be misleading. In this toy example `[1,2,3,4,5]` is a vector representing a single point in a sequence. For example, when dealing with texts, this vector is the word embedding (e.g. of size 300) for a individual word -- that is, each word is represented by 300 features. In your case, each point is represented by 5 features.