# Understanding input shape to PyTorch LSTM

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, tensor

This seems to be one of the most common questions about LSTMs in PyTorch, but I am still unable to figure out what should be the input shape to PyTorch LSTM.

Even after following several posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022734/understanding-a-simple-lstm-pytorch), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408365/trying-to-understand-pytorchs-implementation-of-lstm), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506412/pytorch-lstm-input-dimension)) and trying out the solutions, it doesn't seem to work.

Background: I have encoded text sequences (variable length) in a batch of size 12 and the sequences are padded and packed using `pad_packed_sequence` functionality. `MAX_LEN` for each sequence is 384 and each token (or word) in the sequence has a dimension of 768. Hence my batch tensor could have one of the following shapes: `[12, 384, 768]` or `[384, 12, 768]`.

The batch will be my input to the PyTorch rnn module (lstm here).

According to the PyTorch documentation for [LSTMs](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html#torch.nn.LSTM), its input dimensions are `(seq_len, batch, input_size)` which I understand as following.
`seq_len` - the number of time steps in each input stream (feature vector length).
`batch` - the size of each batch of input sequences.
`input_size` - the dimension for each input token or time step.

`lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=?, hidden_size=?, batch_first=True)`

What should be the exact `input_size` and `hidden_size` values here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have explained the structure of your input, but you haven't made the connection between your input dimensions and the LSTM's expected input dimensions.

Let's break down your input (assigning names to the dimensions):

- `batch_size`: 12
- `seq_len`: 384
- `input_size` / `num_features`: 768

That means the `input_size` of the LSTM needs to be 768.

The `hidden_size` is not dependent on your input, but rather how many features the LSTM should create, which is then used for the hidden state as well as the output, since that is the last hidden state. You have to decide how many features you want to use for the LSTM.

Finally, for the input shape, setting `batch_first=True` requires the input to have the shape `[batch_size, seq_len, input_size]`, in your case that would be `[12, 384, 768]`.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Size: [batch_size, seq_len, input_size]
input = torch.randn(12, 384, 768)

lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=768, hidden_size=512, batch_first=True)

output, _ = lstm(input)
output.size()  # => torch.Size([12, 384, 512])
```

Comment: Official documents explain "input of shape (seq_len, batch, input_size)". So, I think input shape should be (384, 12, 768). https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html

Comment: Sorry, I realize `batch_first` option. This parameter replaces seq_len and batch. So, you are right.

Answer (score -1):

The image passed to CNN layer and lstm layer,the feature map shape changes like this

**BCHW->BCHW(BxCx1xW),**
the CNN's output shape should has the height 1.
then sqeeze the dim of height.
**BCHW->BCW**
in rnn ,shape name changes,[batch ,seqlen,input_size],in image,[batch,width,channel],
**BCW->BWC,**this is batch_first tensor for LSTM layer(like pytorch).
Finally:
**BWC is [batch,seqlen,channel].**