# Pytorch: LSTM (Classification) with FordA Dataset (UCR) not learning

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I have a LSTM with an linear for classification. The shape of `X_train` is `[3601,500,1]` and `y_train` is `[3601]`. The data comes from the [FordA Dataset](http://www.timeseriesclassification.com/description.php?Dataset=FordA).
As I believe the input to the LSTM is correct, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61632584/understanding-input-shape-to-pytorch-lstm). I also tried out different parameters. I checked several questions here on stack overflow but could not find anything that was solving my issues. So do you have any idea why it does not learn?

My LSTM Classifier:

```py
class LSTM_Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, batch_size, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, num_layers):
        super().__init__()

        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim, num_layers=self.num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.output_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        h_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim), requires_grad=True)
        c_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_dim), requires_grad=True)
        out, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, (h_0, c_0))
        f0 = out
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out
```

Training the model results in no learning ("constant" loss):

```py
X_train = X_train.float()
y_train = y_train.long()

batch_size = 50
input_dim = 1
hidden_dim = 512
output_dim = len(set(torch.unique(y_train).tolist()))
number_epochs = 6
num_layers = 1

model = LSTM_Classifier(batch_size, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, num_layers)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loader = DataLoader(TensorDataset(X_train, y_train), shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
losses = []
for epoch in range(number_epochs):
    model.train()
    for X_batch, y_batch in loader:
        y_pred = model(X_batch)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y_batch)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(f"Loss: {loss.item()}")
        losses.append(loss.item())
```

The loss function:
[image: loss over time]

Comment: Try get the model to overfit to a single batch (ie train on the same single batch over and over again). This will help point to where the issue is.